# rounding off double two decimal points

Tags: c++, rounding

```
double x = 9.29;
double y = 8.69;

double diff = floor((x - y)*100+0.5)/100.0;
```

this gives me diff as 0.6 but I need it as 0.60 (two decimal points)
Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: [std::setprecision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision)

Comment: Are you printing this later? That would be when 0.6 and 0.60 would make a difference. And in that case, *how* you print would make a difference on what answer might be better.

Comment: I want to store it in diff variable.

Comment: diff is a double, 0.60 and 0.6 only differ when printed or formatted in a string.

Answer (score 7):

the value of the double is 0.6, because 0.6 and 0.60 are (mathematically) the same thing. What you need is to set the precision when you are *printing* the value not when you are calculating it.

This can be done using

```
cout << setprecision (2) << diff << endl;
```

or

```
printf("%.2f\n", diff);
```

Comment: As diff is a double this ----> `printf("%.2f\n", diff);` causes warning. You should write either `%.2e`/`%.2E` or `%.2lf`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C++ you should do something like that:

```
cout.precision(2);
cout << fixed << diff << "\n";
```

If you ere using C then try this:

```
printf("%.2e\n", diff);
```

The `precision` function determines the maximum number of digits to be written on insertion operations to express floating-point values. So, if you execute this code you will get

```
0.60
```

and if you set the presision to 3 you will get

```
0.600
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solutions but it didn't quite work out for me. I had something like this.

```
 cout << "balance owing: " << balOwed[i] << endl;
```

NOTE: balOwed[i] is an 'array' of type 'double'. It was under a for loop. Anyway,
this would give an output like "Balance owing: 1234.00". However, it was only giving output like "Balance owing: 1234".

I tried using:

```
  cout.presicion(2);
  cout << "balance owing: " << balOwed[i] << endl;
```

it didn't work. So what did finally work for me was the following code:

```
  cout.setf(ios::fixed);
  cout.precision(2);
  cout << "balance owing: " << balOwed[i] << endl;
```

Just to let you guys know, I also tried setprecision(2) and had to include a new library. But that didn't work either. Hope it helps!