# Weight conversion output issue

Tags: c++

I am currently working on a project for my C++ class and have come across an issue that I just cant seem to figure out on my own.

I am creating a weight conversion program that asks the user to input their weight (in kilograms), and outputs their weight in pounds as well as the weight they entered in kilograms (both rounded to 2 decimal places).

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Declarations
    double kg = 0.0;
    double lbs = 0.0;
    double conversionRate = 2.2;

    //INPUT
    cout << "Enter Your Weight (kilograms): ";
    cin >> kg;

    //PROCESS
    lbs = (kg * conversionRate);

    //OUTPUT
    cout << "Weight Entered: " << setprecision(2) << kg << " Kg" << endl;
    cout << "Converts to: " << setprecision(2) << lbs << " lbs" << endl;

    cout << "\n\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output I am getting for pounds:

[image]

These are the variable values when debugging:

[image]

I cant seem to figure out why it is outputting the data that is shown in the screenshot, and why its not showing decimal places as well on the kg?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use fixed.

Either do a

```
cout.precision(2);
cout << "Weight Entered: " << fixed << kg << " Kg" << endl;
cout << "Converts to: " << fixed << lbs << " lbs" << endl;
```

or more like you did

```
cout << "Converts to: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << lbs << " lbs" << endl;
```

This outputs to:

Weight Entered: 63.5028
[image]

[There is a linked case here linked to this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11123815/2285592)

Cheers
Stian

Answer (score 1):

You want to do

> cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << lbs << " lbs" << endl;